# Would like QSettings to preserves comments in settings file

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Currently QSettings library don't preserve comments in the settings file. Is there a feasible way to preserve comments using QSettings?

Comment: what do you mean with "preserve comments" ?

Comment: In the settings file created by QSettings you can't add comments. QSettings don't preserve the comments. For example, "# This option ..."

Comment: QSettings does not support comments. Technically, you can use variables as comments, like `_1=comment here`. Although, I strongly recommend using [toml](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&o=desc&q=toml&s=stars&type=Repositories) instead.